# Laravel Scout Algolia Search - cURL error 6: name lookup timed out

Tags: laravel, algolia

I keep getting "cURL error 6: name lookup timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for [https://xxxxxxx-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/posts/query"](https://xxxxxxx-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/posts/query%22) and sometimes if I put the ip address for xxxxxxx-dsn.algolia.net in the linux hosts files it works very ocassionally. How can you set a timeout for the algolia driver so instead of the 1 second it is at least 3 seconds until timeout?

Something like this - $algolia->setConnectTimeout(3);

But I don't where I could set this.

Answer (score 0):

I hard coded a timeout value of 3 seconds in the GuzzleHttp config and this has stopped all the cURL errors. The default 1 second wasn't suitable when writing test code.